# How do i call get method of Jquery 3.6.1?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

In asp.net core, I want to open a modal by clicking the "Add group" button, so that the content of the Create form is placed inside it. But apparently the $.get method related to jquery does not work at all. The address of the create form is correct, but the output of the program is neither error nor working.

I will be happy if you guide me.

```
 <div class="top-buttons-box mb-2">


    <a class="btn btn-success round" onclick="CreateGroup()">
            <i class="icon-plus"></i>
            افزودن گروه
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="SoftwareGroupsListSection">
        @await Html.PartialAsync("SoftwareGroupsList")

    </div>


    <div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">تیتر مودال</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modalBody">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script >

   // function showMessage() {
    //     alert('Hello everyone!');
    // }
    function CreateGroup(GroupParentId) {
        // alert('Hello everyone!');
       
        $.get("/Admin/SoftwareGroups/Create/" + GroupParentId,
            function (result) {

                 $("#modal").modal();
                 $("#modalLabel").html("افزودن گروه جدید");
                 $("#modalBody").html(result)
               
            });
    }


</script>
```

my action method in Controller is :

```
  // GET: Admin/SoftwareGroups/Create
  public IActionResult Create(int? groupID)
  {
      ViewData["ParentId"] = new SelectList(_context.SoftwareGroups, "GroupId", "GroupTitle");
      ViewBag.ParentId = groupID;
      return View();
  }
```

If I call the showMessage function (instead of CreateGroup) it works fine and displays the message "Hello everyone"

Comment: You function `CreateGroup` you expect a parameter, but you don't provide one in `onclick="CreateGroup()"`

Comment: If no value is sent to the function as input, Null is considered inside the function instead.

Comment: Yes but depending on how your method in the controller looks, that could be a problem. Without more information, like method in controller or error message, we cant help

Comment: `$.Get` - did you check if this exists?    Check console for errors, you will be getting `$.Get is not a function` - try `$.get`

Comment: The name of the function was originally written as $.get (which did not work), I changed the name to $.Get to test, but I forgot to revert the changes.      The problem still exists

Comment: how are you defining $ in the first place? Are you loading a version of jQuery without Ajax support?

Comment: @kourosh did you debug? Do you see the alert in CreateGroup? Have you debugged the C# code?

Comment: @Quentin By the question title, i would hope he loads, jquery V3.6.1

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen that version number has an Ajax and non-Ajax build available.

Comment: @kourosh Also what do you mean by that it does not work at all. Is the url not called? Is their an error in the console?

Comment: Yes the url is not called.

Comment: Add this line inside your event handler as the first line `console.log($.fn.jquery)` - open page, F12 for console, report message here - and look for other errors in the console while there

Comment: Yes the url is not called. Also, when I click the CreateGroup button, nothing happens in the console. Content inside the console, before and after clicking on CreateGroup:
https://s6.uupload.ir/files/capture_dk7s.jpg

Comment: @kourosh — You need to look at the Console in the **browser's** Developer Tools to see client-side JS errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the url like:  `$.get("/Admin/SoftwareGroups/Create", { groupID: GroupParentId },` the demo as below:

```
<a class="btn btn-success round" onclick="CreateGroup(1)">
            <i class="icon-plus"></i>
            افزودن گروه
        </a>
    </div>
//do your staff...
<script>

    // function showMessage() {
     //     alert('Hello everyone!');
     // }
     function CreateGroup(GroupParentId) {
        alert(GroupParentId);

            $.get("/Admin/SoftwareGroups/Create", {  groupID: GroupParentId },
             function (result) {

                    $("#modal").modal('show');
                  $("#modalLabel").html("افزودن گروه جدید");
                  $(".modalBody").html(result)

             });
       
     }


</script>
```

This is only for excute the create action, if you want  the content of the Create form is placed inside modal,  you can create a partial view(_CreatePartialView.cshtml) to set the content of the Create form, and return it.

eg:_CreatePartialView.cshtml

```
the content of the Create form is placed inside modal
//do your staff...
```

The action:

```
// GET: Admin/SoftwareGroups/Create
  public IActionResult Create(int? groupID)
  {
      ViewData["ParentId"] = new SelectList(_context.SoftwareGroups, "GroupId", "GroupTitle");
      ViewBag.ParentId = groupID;
       return PartialView("_CreatePartialView");
  }
```

result:
[image]

**Update**

```
public IActionResult Create(int? groupID)
  {
      ViewData["ParentId"] = new SelectList(_context.SoftwareGroups, "GroupId", "GroupTitle");
      ViewBag.ParentId = groupID;
      ViewBag.list = new SelectList(_context.SoftwareGroups, "GroupId", "GroupTitle");
      var model = new User(); //any model you  want
      return PartialView("CreateGroupPartialView",model);
  }
```

Then in the CreateGroupPartialView:

```
the content of the Create form is placed inside modal

@model User

<form>
    <input  type="text"/>

    <select name="anyproperty" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.list"></select>
</form>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks - as you said "This is only for excute the create action" my action is executed. But the form was not displayed . my action method is  public IActionResult Create(int? groupID)
 {
     ViewData["ParentId"] = new SelectList(_context.SoftwareGroups, "GroupId", "GroupTitle");
     ViewBag.ParentId = groupID;
     return PartialView("CreateGroupPartialView");
 }

Comment: and my view is   just      @model DataLayer.SoftwareGroup

<h4>SoftwareGroup</h4>

Comment: @kourosh  We need to add the form data in the CreateGroupPartialView, not just `@model DataLayer.SoftwareGroup`  , and pass the model to the CreateGroupPartialView if we want to bind some data for the model. If we just show the SelectList , we just use ViewBag to pass the list from action to view, depend on you. Please have a look at my update.

Comment: Hi @kourosh, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?